# Create form in sharepoint and data goes to a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, powerapp, powerapps-forms, microsoft-forms

Is it possible to create a form in SharePoint, and that data that's filled out will go to a list. But have the form be smart enough to reference the list to know if an item has already been added.

An example would be this if our sales org gets a new client, we want the person who gets the client to fill out all sorts of info. But say they try and do it again, it will stop them and say, "the client has already been added please go here to fill out additional information" (which would be on the list it is sending to)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a column for the client name and then set that column to enforce unique values (you can do this when you create the column or via column settings).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could go to [this forum](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Community/ct-p/PowerApps1#) which is dedicated to PowerApp for more professional help.